# Maven Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:jar:1.6 in pom.xml?

Tags: maven

I have done a check out from svn as in Eclipse(luna) as "Checkout Maven Project as SCM".After doing that i am getting g error in pom.xml.How to resolve the error.?Below is the error...

***Console.log:***

```
> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]  [INFO] Using the builder
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder
> with a thread count of 1 [INFO]                                       
> [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building Bosch FS module 1.1-snapshot [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Downloading:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/jaxb2-maven-plugin/1.6/jaxb2-maven-plugin-1.6.pom
> [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 0.717 s [INFO] Finished at:
> 2015-01-12T09:33:05+01:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/76M [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
> for org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:jar:1.6: Could not transfer
> artifact org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:pom:1.6 from/to central
> (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown
> host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the
> full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible
> solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Thank you,
Siva

Comment: Sounds like having network/proxy problems or not correctly configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem
I think you are not able to download from maven central repository the required artifacts because central repository is blocked by your proxy server.

Possible solution
Steps
1-goto C:\Users\username.m2 and delete repository folder.
2-create an settings.xml at the same location

```
<settings>
<proxies>
 <proxy>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <host>ip of your proxy</host>
  <port>port of your proxy</port>
  <username>your machine login username</username>
  <password>your machine login password</password>
  <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
</proxies>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 1):

The url for the central repository seems to be an old one. The recommended url is the following https://repo1.maven.org/maven2